# Divs will not return on mouseleave in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have some jquery that moves the triangles next to it when I hover over the text. Mouseover works fine, however mouseleave does not return the triangles to its normal states.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".website_logo").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".right_triangle").css({
             'marginLeft' : "30px" 
        });
        $(".left_triangle").css({
             'marginRight' : "30px" 
        });
    });

    $(".website_logo").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".right_triangle").css({
             'marginRight' : "30px" 
        });
        $(".left_triangle").css({
             'marginLeft' : "30px" 
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reset the margin to its original value instead of setting the opposite margin.

As you did not provide any HTML or CSS, I assume the following.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".website_logo").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".right_triangle").css({
             'marginLeft' : "30px" 
        });
        $(".left_triangle").css({
             'marginRight' : "30px" 
        });
    });

    $(".website_logo").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".right_triangle").css({
             'marginLeft' : "0" 
        });
        $(".left_triangle").css({
             'marginRight' : "0" 
        });
    });
});
```